# how to use find -exec command with {} option

Tags: shell, unix, find, exec

How to display argument values using -exec option. 
I want to display like -

```
    jsvn sd/SQL
    jsvn sd/SQL/mxtools
    jsvn sd/SQL/qatools
```

but the below one doesn't satisfy.

```
/SQL 113>find $PWD -type d  -exec echo "jsvn sd"{} \;
jsvn sd{}
jsvn sd{}
jsvn sd{}
```

but when i use space It works but It doesn't satisfy the req.

```
/SQL 114>find $PWD -type d  -exec echo "jsvn sd" {} \;
jsvn sd /SQL
jsvn sd /SQL/tools1
jsvn sd /SQL/tools2
```

Comment: Use `find "$PWD"` intead of `find $PWD` (the last one doesn't support spaces in the current directory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find $PWD -type d -exec printf "jsvn sd%s\n" {} +
```